# Date comparison giving wrong result

Tags: datetime, knockout.js, compare

In my current task, I have to compare the given date with the current date. I have to add this date comparison module in Knockout JS. The given date format is like below,

```
User.StartingDate()
Mon Jun 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    __proto__: Invalid Date
```

Then for the current date I used,

```
var dateToday = new Date();
```

Which also resulted in the following format,

```
Tue May 31 2016 16:06:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    __proto__: Invalid Date
```

But this two things resulted in two different time notations. And I just want to compare given date with the current date so I have tried like,

```
User.StartingDate().toLocaleDateString()
"‎06‎-‎08‎-‎2015"
dateToday.toLocaleDateString()
"‎05‎-‎31‎-‎2016"
```

But while comparing it,

```
User.StartingDate().toLocaleDateString() < dateToday.toLocaleDateString()
// result is FALSE
// but 06‎-‎08‎-‎2015 < 05‎-‎31‎-‎2016 is TRUE
```

I struggled for a whole day, but can't figure it out why the things getting wrong.

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: I am doing this in IE

Comment: IE version 11.0.9600.18053

Answer (score 1):

For IE9 and higher + modern browsers you can use [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). Because of the structure of that kind of string it's easy to do `====`, `>`, and `<` comparisons.

For below IE8 you can use a polyfill. Aforementioned MDN link has an example.

If you have to do a lot of date/time stuff, or you have to support timezones and so on, I recommend incorporating [the momentjs library](http://momentjs.com/).

Demo:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.date1txt = ko.observable("Mon Jun 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
  self.date2txt = ko.observable("Mon Jun 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
  
  self.date1 = ko.computed(() => new Date(self.date1txt()));
  self.date2 = ko.computed(() => new Date(self.date2txt()));  
  
  self.isGreater = ko.computed(() => self.date1().toISOString() > self.date2().toISOString());
  self.isSmaller = ko.computed(() => self.date1().toISOString() < self.date2().toISOString());
  self.isEqual = ko.computed(() => self.date1().toISOString() === self.date2().toISOString());
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
pre { background: white; padding: 10px; color: #333; font: 11px consolas; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Edit date1 input in txt format: <input data-bind="textInput: date1txt"><br>
Edit date2 input in txt format: <input data-bind="textInput: date2txt"><br>
<hr>
date1 &gt; date2 ... <strong data-bind="text: isGreater"></strong><br>
date1 &lt; date2 ... <strong data-bind="text: isSmaller"></strong><br>
date1 === date2 ... <strong data-bind="text: isEqual"></strong><br>
<hr>Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: This date comparison should support in all web browsers in my application.

Comment: Sorry, but that comment makes little sense to me. Can you specify what parts of my answer about browser-compatability were unclear? And perhaps also what you mean with "all web browsers in my application"? You haven't specified *anything* on browsers and their versions in your question...